# Error While installing library "pip install python-csv"

Tags: python, csv, cmd, pip, face-recognition

I was trying to run a project "Face Recognition Based Attendance Monitoring System".
In the requirements it mentioned this module need to be installed

- pip install python-csv

while installing **python-csv**  I am getting this error [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvhW3.png),
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x06eK.png)

I have also installed **visual studio with c++ build tools**,
**wheel*

for the kind note, I did the same thing on my friend's laptop which has an Intel processor and I am having AMD and does this is a cause of the problem?

Comment: do you have `wheel` installed? `pip install wheel` ? I had the wheel error far time ago.. fix by that.

Comment: yes i have wheel installed after that I got this error